# Getting error while converting long to string

Tags: java

I have a project, in which there is a setter method as shown below:

```
public Long getvoiceId() {
    return voiceId;
}
```

Now, I am using `DOM parser` to generate the xml from the object itself, but for this particular field, I am getting compilation error as shown below.
It always give me the compilation error, indicating that the method's return type should be changed to string.

```
Element voiceId = doc.createElement("voiceId");
InvoiceId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Long.toString(irm.getInvoiceId())));
voiceReferenceNotificationMessage.appendChild(voiceId);
```

As you can see above, I am explicitly casting it using `Long.toString`, but I am still getting `NullPointerException` for this.

Please advise on how to proceed, thanks.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: it is probably because `irm` or `voiceId` are null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4):

Your getter returns a `Long` (an object) instead of a `long` (primitive). An object may be *null*, while a (initialized) primitive alwaws has to have a value. `Long.toString()` however takes a `long`, which means the VM needs to unbox the `Long` by automatically inserting a `.longValue()` call on it. If the object is *null*, you get a `NullPointerException`